# Can't highlight text in Combo Box

Tags: .net, vb.net

I've recently run into an issue with a Combo Box in .Net using VB.  For some reason the user cannot select text by clicking and dragging on text in the Combo Box. They however can double click to select the text but that only works if there are no spaces or special characters.  After selecting an item in the Combo Box it does show the value and it's highlighted.

I've looked online and haven't found any links with the same problem.  I've looked to see if a Data Source was blocking it and no luck there either.  I'm filling the Combo Boxes with a loop like:

```
ComboBox1.Items.Add("Thing1)
```

I expect the Combo Box to let the user highlight the text so they can delete or copy and paste the text. Any ideas why highlighting text is blocked/locked?

Comment: Do you have events related to mouse/keyboard input or focus change (MouseEnter/Leave, MouseDown/MouseUp, Enter, Leave etc.)? What happens if you move the focus from another control to your ComboBox using the `Tab` key?

Comment: On some of them I do yes, but I'm currently working on a new form that I haven't added any of those types of events and I'm still getting the same issue.  If I move focus into the control by tabbing it highlights all of the text.

Comment: What is the DropDownStyle of the combo? What do you mean by clicking and dragging? Usually it is just a click.

Comment: DropDownStyle is set to DropDown.  When I say clicking and dragging, I mean when you try to highlight the text.

Comment: We're seeing the exact same issue with the ComboBox in our C# WinForms application. The issue seems to have started around the time .NET 4.8 was released, but we're targeting .NET 4.6.2. Has anyone had any luck solving this?

Comment: @JonTackabury Sorry I was never able to figure this out. Next thing I might try is to create my own Combo Box and see if that cures it.

Comment: It looks like this is a .NET bug in 4.8, we'll just have to wait for Microsoft to release a fix. https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/630431/combobox-text-no-longer-selectable-with-mouse-afte.html

Comment: If you are affected by this issue, please consider upvoting it in the VS link provided by @JonTackabury